# C/C++: How to store data in a file in B tree

Tags: c++, c, file, b-tree

It appears to me that one way of storing data in a B-tree as a file can be done efficiently with C using binary file with a sequence (array) of structs, with each struct representing a node. One can thus connect the individual nodes with approach that will be similar to creating linked lists using arrays. But then the problem that props up would be deletion of a node, as erasing only a few bytes in the middle in a huge file is not possible.

One way of deleting could be to keep track of 'empty' nodes until a threshold cutoff is reached and then make another file that will discard the empty nodes. But this is tedious.

Is there a better approach from the simplicity/efficiency point of view for deleting, or even representing a B-tree in a file?

TIA,
-Sviiya

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about B-trees or binary trees.

Comment: B-trees. But I guess for the purpose of storing as files the issue would be the same?

Comment: BTW, C and C++ are two different languages.  If you are writing code that works on both, then add the C++ tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a very quick search and dug up this: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/WB C source: http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/wb/wb/c/ - it seems to offer disk-based B-tree style databases - although taking a look at "delete.c" it seemed to imply if you delete a node everything down from it would be taken out - if that's the correct behaviour then it sounds like something that might help?

Also - B-trees are often used in filesystems - could you not take a look at some filesystem code?

My own inclination is that of a file-system - if you have a B-tree of fixed-size, whenever you "delete" a node rather than attempting to remove the reference, just set the value to whatever means nothing in your code. Then, have a clean-up thread running that checks if anyone has the file open for reading and if all's quiet blocks the file and tidies up.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Ninefingers. :) Will certainly have to read it.

Because deletion can be frequent, accounting for them should be efficient. I would expect some of these operations could perhaps be delayed, but I would need to read the code to see if there is a better option.

I also intend to use it for a filesystem later, but then the implementation would be different as the size would be constant. So the design will need to take that into account.

Comment: Hmm I agree. That code claims to do what you need and a cursory glance at viewcvs suggests it might - without sitting down and rebuilding your problem though it's hard to tell... I think filesystems do just "zero" elements they wish to delete and assign to any zero element but I could have that wrong. Either way, if this doesn't answer it please do open up the question again!

Comment: The questions does answer what I was looking for, and I already found out about file truncating and hence the problem of deleting data from the middle is circumvented. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

For implementing B-Trees in a file, you can use the file offset instead of pointers.  Also, you can implement a "file memory manager", so that you can re-use deleted items in the file.

In order to fully recover the deleted blocks in a B-Tree file, you will have to recreate the B-Tree in a new file.  Also remember the most OSes have no methods for truncating files.  A portable method for truncating a file is to write a new file and destroy the old.

Another suggestion is to partition the file into B-Tree partition and data (item) partition.  A B-Tree partition will contain the pages.  The leaf pages will contain offsets to the data items.  The data partition will be a section in the file containing data items.  You may end up creating more than one of each partition and the partitions may be interleaved.

I spent much time playing with a file based B-Tree, until I gave up and decided to let a database program (or server) handle the data for me.

Comment: Sounds interesting. This exercise of mine is to get some exposure to low level coding. I am mainly interested in Linux based systems and it supports file truncation. :)

Comment: Most OS's *do* have functions to truncate files. In Linux, BSDs, Windows you can set the file length to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Berkley DB as well. It works well with C programs and implements B+ tree.

Comment: Yep, but I want to write my own code to get the real feel. :)

Comment: Agree. Writing on your own is fine to get the real feel.

BBD is very sophisticated database and provides many features that normal code wouldn't. In case of actual product deployment, I would choose BDB. Reinventing wheel would be difficult here.